# loading data from a json

Tags: arrays, extjs, combobox, store

i have data available i want to load like this:

```
{
"success": true,
"message": null,
"total": null,
"data": [{
    "clockTypes": ["_12", "_24"],
    "speedTypes": ["MPH", "KMPH"],
    "scheduleTypes": ["DEFAULT", "AUTO"]
}]}
```

i am normaly load the data like this

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.comboTimezone', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,
        storeId: 'MyJsonStore5',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'json/timezone.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}});
```

now do i get the clocktypes as one record in my combobox. how can i get two records: _12 and _24 in my combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `root` should be... `data.clockTypes` I -think- ( though I'm not really sure if that would work. )

Hijacking that ajax call to load the data is a bit awkward, since thats not really the right format for the store to consume( is it? )

Ideally you want...

```
{
"success": true,
"message": null,
"total": null,
"data": [{
   name: "_12", name:"_24"]
}]}

constructor: function(cfg) {
var me = this;
cfg = cfg || {};
me.callParent([Ext.apply({
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId: 'MyJsonStore5',
    valueField:'name',
    displayField:'name',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'json/timezone.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
}, cfg)]);
}});
```

Though this does mean you end up with more ajax calls. Alternatively, if you've got your heart set on populating 3 comboboxes (I'm kinda guessing that's what your trying to do ) from 1 ajax call, then you need to generate the stores dynamically based off the data from 
an Ext.request()

However if you cant mess with the data, then we can...

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.store.comboTimezone', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        Ext.define('TZ', extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            name: 'name'
        }])
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'TZ',
            storeId: 'MyJsonStore5',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'json/timezone.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
        //hacky, but works i guess
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'my.json',
            success: function(response) {
                var text = response.responseText;
                var json = Ext.JSON.decode(text);
                for(var i =0);i<json.data.lenght();i++;){
                    Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('MyJsonStore5').add(Ext.create('TZ',{name:json.data[i]}))
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

*barrring typos which create bugs.

Basically you call the url, get the data as raw json, and then process it into a format that your store can read.

It's a bit of a hack unfortunately.

Comment: Yes that is what i want to do. problem is that i don't have influence on the format of the output :(

Comment: Meh. See edit for hacky workaround if you can't influence output.